# After deleting the 2nd website showing error

Tags: magento2.3

I have deleted the 2nd Magento website and after deleting the 2nd website showing the following error please help me. how to resolve this issue

> {"0":"The website with id 2 that was requested wasn't found. Verify
> the website and try again.","1":"#1
> Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getWebsite(2) called at
> [generated/code/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php:135]\n#2
> Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getWebsite(2)
> called at
> [vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Website.php:31]\n#3
> Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Website->getScope(2) called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php:49]\n#4
> Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('website',
> 2) called at
> [vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php:100]\n#5
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->loadConfig()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Source/RuntimeConfigSource.php:72]\n#6
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('')
> called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ConfigSourceAggregated.php:40]\n#7
> Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get() called
> at
> [vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader.php:60]\n#8
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader->read() called at
> [generated/code/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader/Proxy.php:95]\n#9
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader\Proxy->read()
> called at
> [vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php:395]\n#10
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->readData() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/Cache/LockGuardedCacheLoader.php:103]\n#11
> Magento\Framework\Cache\LockGuardedCacheLoader->lockedLoadData('SYSTEM_CONFIG',
> &Closure#000000004a020b5d00000000584c7219#,
> &Closure#000000004a020b5e00000000584c7219#,
> &Closure#000000004a020b5f00000000584c7219#) called at
> [vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php:281]\n#12
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->loadDefaultScopeData('default')
> called at
> [vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php:207]\n#13
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->getWithParts('default/admin/ur...')
> called at
> [vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php:181]\n#14
> Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/admin/ur...')
> called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php:132]\n#15
> Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system',
> 'default/admin/ur...') called at
> [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Config.php:51]\n#16
> Magento\Backend\App\Config->getValue('admin/url/use_cu...')
> called at
> [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Area/FrontNameResolver.php:109]\n#17
> Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver->getFrontName(false)
> called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Helper/Data.php:209]\n#18
> Magento\Backend\Helper\Data->getAreaFrontName(false) called at
> [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Helper/Data/Interceptor.php:128]\n#19
> Magento\Backend\Helper\Data\Interceptor->getAreaFrontName() called
> at
> [app/code/Mageplaza/SeoUrl/App/Request/BackendPathInfoProcessor.php:71]\n#20
> Mageplaza\SeoUrl\App\Request\BackendPathInfoProcessor->process(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004a020b2600000000584c7219#,
> '/vb_update_36361...') called at
> [generated/code/Magento/Backend/App/Request/PathInfoProcessor/Proxy.php:95]\n#21
> Magento\Backend\App\Request\PathInfoProcessor\Proxy->process(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000004a020b2600000000584c7219#,
> '/vb_update_36361...') called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/Http.php:147]\n#22
> Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->getOriginalPathInfo() called
> at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/Http.php:162]\n#23
> Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->getPathInfo() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/App/Request/Http.php:217]\n#24
> Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http->getFrontName() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:111]\n#25
> Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]\n#26
> Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http#000000004a020b7500000000584c7219#) called at
> [index.php:39]\n","url":"/vb_update_36361990_admin/mpreports/dashboard/","script_name":"/index.php","report_id":"6ed5c8ee4c0cccfc43d62bc180c8e2543d88f8bc1a09e5656d4dd2fdaf68444c"}

Comment: How was the site deleted?

Comment: @Oscprofessionals I have 2 websites under 1 Magento installation and i have delete 2nd  website

Comment: What was the URL requested. Was the browser cookies and cache cleared. Also was the server cache flushed and code deployed. any chance that code is in cache. Also check if there is any hardcoded store ID value or an entry of store id 2 left in some table and that didn't got deleted when store was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided error trace, looks like some of the records in *core_config_data* table haven't been removed when you deleted the second website. So please try running the following MySQL query and then **flush cache**:

```
DELETE FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `scope` IN ('website', 'websites') AND `scope_id` = '2';
```

Comment: yes our issue is resolved  thanks